# Has anyone besides Bruce Wayne donned the batsuit and taken on the Batman persona?

Tags: batman

Is Bruce Wayne the only person to act as Batman?

Or has anyone else ever wore the batsuit to go fight crime?

Why did Bruce Wayne allow somebody else to wear the batsuit?

Accepting answers with quotes or images from official sources.

Comment: Yes. Alfred has on multiple occasions. Other answers are also possibe. Are you looking for any particular continuity?

Comment: Comics? Novels? Movies? TV shows?

Comment: @Lexible All of those if they are official sources. Is there an official canon for Batman?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Is there something wrong with asking this question? Or how it was asked?

Comment: There are multiple "canon" definitions. For instance: there have been comics stories where the stories were not "canonical" at the time of publishing: historically, DC Comics called these "imaginary stories." The TV shows and movies have not been canonical in the comics, and (generally) vice versa. Some of the animated stories in the late 1960s or 1970s (including *Super Friends* and appearances in *Scooby Doo* might treat the 1960s live-action TV show as canon; they tend to fit together well, and may have been voiced by West and Ward....

Comment: ... The four 1990s movies are a canon to themselves, as are the three 2000s movies by Christopher Nolan. It seems unlikely that the DC cinematic universe formed by *Man of Steel*, *Batman vs Superman*, *Wonder Woman*, and *Justice League* consider the Nolan movies as canon, as the situation and the end of the Nolan movies would contradict what we see in *BvS*....

Comment: ... There have been at least 4 separate Batman animated series in the last 30 years. *Batman: the Animated Series* (which continued throughout the 1990s under multiple names) forms a single continuity with *Superman: the Animated Series*, *Justice League*, *Justice League Unlimited* and *Batman Beyond* (at least). The animated series since then (*The Batman* in the 2000s, *Batman: the Brave and the Bold*, and *Beware the Batman*, both in the 2010s) don't form a continuity with any other shows. Each of these had their own comics, which may be canonical with the shows.

Answer (score 14):

Several. Among others...

[Jean-Claude Valley, aka Azrael](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Azrael_(Jean-Paul_Valley)) took over the identity after Batman had his back broken by Bane. Bruce eventually had to fight him to take the title back after he recovered and Valley had become extreme and brutal in the role.

[image]

When Bruce was believed killed by Darkseid in *Final Crisis*, Dick Grayson, aka the first Robin, took up the cowl. He'd donned the costume before for various reasons, but this time he assumed it was permanent.

[image]

Other characters have filled in. Superman took up the costume a few times, one of the funniest being an animated episode where Bruce went missing so Robin went to Superman for help.

[image]

For plot reasons, Superman pretended to be Batman. The funny came when he had to fight Bane. Bane vs Batman, dangerous fight. Bane vs Superman Pretending to be Batman, curb-stomping.

James Gordon served as Batman during the *[Endgame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Endgame)* story arc.

[image]

Then of course, *[Batman Beyond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Beyond)* was all about [Terry McGinnis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(Terry_McGinnis)) becoming Bruce's successor.

[image]